# How can i fix this kind of exception? ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

The exception message returns:

> Year, Month, and Day parameters
>   describe an un-representable DateTime.

The exception hits the `monthCalendar1.SelectionStart`

```
            DateTime check_date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;

            for (int index = 0; index <= 5; index++)
            {
                check_date = new DateTime(check_date.Year, check_date.Month, check_date.Day - index);

            }
```

I also tried this one. but another exception has occured `TargetInvocationException`

```
                DateTime check_date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;

                for (int index = 0; index <= 5; index++)
                {
                    check_date = check_date.AddDays(-index);

                }
```

Exception details:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>     Message=Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
>          at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
>          at TestGetDates.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\ngd11\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestGetDates\TestGetDates\Program.cs:line 15
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException:

Comment: FYI, there's a bug in **native Win32 DateTimePicker** when using Custom DateFormat like 'MM/yyyy'.
see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/553375/system-argumentoutofrangeexception-year-month-and-day-parameters-describe-an-un-representable-datetime) the description.


and there's a workaround [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/69b10b5b-a034-426e-a045-2bed8a1637a3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  date_tax.Day - index
```

this might be producing a negative number that is causing this exception, debug and check its value.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I changed that one to `AddDays(index)` but another exception will occur something like targetinvocationexception

Comment: Please provide some more information i-e 1. what you want to achieve ? 2. Exception Stacktrace (if you can)

Comment: never mind. :) I just used a different approach :) thanks anyways